# High current PCB traces

Tags: pcb-design

I am doing a PCB layout with one +12VDC input fused at 20A which breaks up into multiple fused branches that vary from 2 to 10A each. The input is a screw terminal barrier block and the fuses are vertical fuse holders for blade-style fuses.

I tried to lay it out so the main current path (running horizontally through the middle) has the shortest distance to all the branches. The scale here is that the board width (left to right) is about 2 inches.

Trace width calculators tell me that I need a 370mil trace if using 2oz copper, but how does this apply when the traces are short as shown? I can't really double it on the bottom layer because it would cut my ground plane. The width shown at the input is about 180mil.

Thanks :)

[image: Text]

Comment: Move one obstacle and you can make that central trace MUCH wider right across - probably double that 370 mil recommendation, more like 0.75 inch. (And you can ask for 2oz copper)

Comment: 370 mil of 2 oz copper? That's some massive overdimensioning. How little acceptable temperature increase do you specify that you get so high widths? There's no reason to assume your trace can't get 30 K hotter than environment, usually. Putting these fuses diagonally seems to complicate your layout, too. So, maybe try putting them straight and use a filled zone to really maximize the copper area.

Comment: Thermal track rise is per unit length, not total..  use both sides and show schematic, consider jumper or busbar

Comment: @MarcusMüller That was with the default 10K temperature rise. This thing will be housed in plastic so I do want to be a little on the cautious side. By increasing it to 30K then the shown trace widths would work. The fuses diagonally was for fingertip access in removing them, though I suppose I could stagger them in a way that still works.

Comment: The tables assume the worst case, i.e., that you are in the middle of a *long* trace. Your traces are short so you have extra heat conduction at the ends via the fuses. Your temp rise may be half of what the table predicts.

Comment: the fuses will produce heat too.